# Selecting objects that belong to a specific class when iterating through list of objects

Tags: python, object, oop

I am trying to find a way of iterating over a list of objects and determining what class the objects belong to, some objects are of the parent class and some are of the child class.
This is what I what I am kind of expecting but have no idea how to make it work.

```
class example1():
     def __init__(self,attribute1,attribute2,attribute3,etc):
          self.attribute1 = attribute1
          self.attribute2 = attribute2
          *etc...*

class example2(example1):
     def __init__(self,newAttribute1,newAttribute2,newAttribute3,etc):
          self.newAttribute1 = newAttribute1
          self.newAttribute2 = newAttribute2
          *etc...*

*Code to create a list of a mix of both class example1 and example2*

for object in listOfObjects:
     if object *belongs to* example1:
         *do this*
     else:
          *do this instead*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) builtin function. For your case you can do something like:

```py
if isinstance(object, example1):
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Comment: Also avoid using builtins as an identifier. In your case: `for object in listOfObjects`, `object` shadows the builtin identifier [`object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object). You can suffix these with a trailing underscore to prevent conflicts with builtins.